# Peer-to-Peer Publication SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication, p2p

I am creating a peer to peer publication between 3 nodes, i configure all nodes like this tutorial [How to Setup Peer To Peer Replication in SQL Server 2016 - SQL Server 2016 DBA Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tr4ALODSl9g) but when i inserta data in any node table the information does not appear in the others database tables.

[image]

I don't know if I have to change any parameters in the server configuration or sql server configuration.

Comment: There are many online guides to troubleshooting replication. For example, are your SQL Agent jobs running? What does the replication monitor say?

Comment: off-topic for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Agent jobs have multiple errors.

[image]